# How to automate dummy variable creation from categorical variable in Stata?

Tags: regression, stata, dummy-variable

How can `generate` for creationg of dummies/indicators from factor/categorical variable be automated?

Solution comes from Nick: `tabulate group, generate(g)`

```
* Load data
clear
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nlswork

* Set panel structure
xtset idcode year

* Delete other variables
keep idcode year ln_wage union tenure age race occ_code

* Complete Cases
drop if union ==.
drop if tenure ==.
drop if occ_code ==.

* Generate dummies automatically
tabulate race, generate(r)
tabulate occ_code, generate(occ)
generate tr1 = tenure*r1
generate tr2 = tenure*r2
generate tr3 = tenure*r3

* Interaction with factor notation
reg ln_wage c.tenure##i.race i.occ_code age union
*margins, dydx(tenure) post
estimates store reg_factor

* Interaction without factor notation
reg ln_wage tenure r1 r2 r3 tr1 tr2 tr3 age union  ///
occ1 occ2 occ3 occ4 occ5 occ6 occ7 occ8 occ9 occ10 occ11 occ12 occ13
*margins, dydx(tenure) post
estimates store reg_dummies 

estimates table reg_factor reg_dummies
```

Comment: You know about factor variable syntax. That's the best method of using indicator (you say dummy) variables. Otherwise the `generate()` option of `tabulate` is easier than defining indicators one by one. More at https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-dummy-variables/ and https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099

Comment: Thank Nick, after `tabulate occ_code, generate(g)` what would be a good way for including about 50 dummies in a regression? Putting them in a local seems to be as inefficient as copying them into the regression directly.

Comment: My comment already addresses that. Using factor variable syntax is the best method for specifying indicators to a regression or other model. Period.  The only advantage of `tabulate` is if you need the variables for other purposes.  Please read the linked FAQ as a minimum.

Comment: Nick, I enjoyed your article "Speaking Stata". I like how to trace the usage of "dummy" to the 50s. The FAQ already answered my first issue, `tabulate` + `gen` is the best way to automate dummy creation. I'm still searching for a loop structure to include lots of controls and interaction dummies in my regression (since my Stata commands and procedures do not allow for factor notation). Best regards